# Trying to install Audit_log Plugin on MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, percona, audit

I'm trying to install the Percona Audit_log plugin for my instance of MySQL.

I ran it previously so I know it works ok with MySQL (I'm sure it says so in the documentation anyway).

I have MySQL 5.5.47, so I downloaded the files for Percona server 5.5.47-37.7 and extracted the `audit_log.so` file.

I put that file into my plugin directory on the server (debian), but when I try to install it I get:

`INSTALL PLUGIN audit_log SONAME 'audit_log.so';`

`Error Code: 1126. 
Cant open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/audit_log.so'
(errno: 13 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/audit_log.so: undefined symbol: my_pthread_fastmutex_init)`

I checked the permissions are the same as all the other files in that directory. Does anyone know if I need a different version for MySQL 5.5.47, I assumed the Percona versions matched the MySQL versions, or any ideas on it why it wont install?

Comment: did you download the Linux generic tarball from Percona repos? I just tried it myself, MySQL 5.5.47 Community Server using Percona Server 5.5.47 audit log plugin and it worked

Comment: I did yes, it was `Percona-Server-5.5.47-rel37.7-Linux.x86_64.ssl098.tar.gz` I guess I have a different problem then.

Comment: Try ssl100 or ssl101, I used `*-ssl101.tar.gz`

Comment: cheers, I tried the 101 version , but it made no difference.

Comment: can you run `nm /usr/bin/mysqld | grep my_pthread_fastmutex_init`, if there is no output then could be that your build was not compiled with the `--with-fast-mutex option/WITH_FAST_MUTEXES` feature

Comment: I think you may have it right there. I ran `nm /usr/sbin/mysqld | grep my_pthread_fastmutex_init` and got `no symbols`. I guess because it is the version of MySQL compiled for debian (`5.5.47-0+deb8u1-log`) they left that out. Oh well, I'll have to stick to using the older version (5.5.44 version seems to be ok).

Comment: Might you consider migrating to Percona-Server to enable the use of the plugin? It's a drop in replacement and you might also benefit from many of the performance improvements patched into the alternative.